# "Hit", "Strike" or "Beat"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

After searching many dictionaries and reading some articles, still I'n not able to tell these three worda apart so that I could fill in the blank below! Please have a look on the following sentences and let me know which choice is more suitable for each blank:

> 1 - During the competition, my rival.............hard my leg with his stick! 
>   2 - During the competition, my rival ............ his stick to my leg!

a) hit 
b) beat 
c) struck

Comment: The past tense of is ***beat***, not ***beated*** (the past *participle* is ***beaten***, as used in passive / adjectival contexts such as *We were beaten by a better team, Souffles are made using beaten eggs*). But it's probably not suitable for your context, since it implies ***repeatedly and deliberately*** struck/hit. I advise sticking to ***hit***, if only because it's far more common than ***struck***. Note that it's *He hit my leg hard*, not *He hit hard my leg*.

Comment: Sorry for the childish mistake; I have changed it @FumbleFingers. ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm going to imply "only one hit" rather than "repeatedly hit".

Comment: Apart from the fact that ***beat*** implies repetition, I suspect you won't "learn" much from this particular word choice question. Alternative verbs include (but aren't limited to) ***bang, bash, clout, smash, smack, thump, wallop***, but there won't be universal agreement on possible different nuances conveyed by any given choice there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The past tense of *beat* is *beat*, not *beated*.
2. Your first sentence is unidiomatic, because the adverb *hard* does not normally come between the verb and its object.
3. All three will do in your first sentence (though the meaning varies slightly), and none of them will do in your second sentence.
4. Using *beat* in your first sentence implies that the rival hit your leg repeatedly. *Hit* and *struck* do not imply that (though they do not exclude the possibility). The only difference I can find betwen *hit* and *struck* here is that *struck* is more formal: people wouldn't say it in ordinary speech.

Comment: Thank you @Colin Fine; just please tell me about ilusing the simple verb "hit" along with a direct object! Would it sound normal to say: "My rival **hit his stick to/onto my leg"**?

Comment: No, @A-friend, it wouldn't. It would be understandable, but not normal: the object of _hit_ is the thing that you strike, not the thing you strike it with.

Comment: Thank you very much @Colin Fine; great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both *hit* and *struck* work well. *Hit* is slightly less formal: I might be inclined to tell my wife that a car *hit* another car, but I would tell the police the car *struck* the other car.

*Beat* (no "-ed") usually suggests a series of strikes. For example, "He beat his head against the wall" or would mean he hit the wall with his head several times, but the exact number is not important. Likewise, to say "The wife beat her cheating husband" means she hit, kicked, or threw things at him for a few minutes.

There are some other small changes (or "tweaks") you might make:

> During the competition, my rival **hit** my leg **hard** with his stick.
>
> During the competition, my rival **struck** my leg with his stick.

Adding *to*, like sentence 1 of your example, is unusual for violent verbs like "hit", "beat", or "struck." In fact, adding "to" can suggest gentleness or exactness: you might say, "The mother **pressed** her nose **to** her daughter's head," or "The electrician **touched** sensor **to** the live wire."

Comment: Point taken @Dan Oliver; just would it sound normal to say: "My rival **hit his stick onto my leg"**? I mean does the verb "hit" take any direct object like this sentence?